# unable to save image in SQLite in iPhone

Tags: objective-c

can anybody tell me why i am unable to insert an image in sqlite. Some time i get error like:
    1)(sqlite3_step(stm) == SQLITE_DONE) , getting value as 21.
    2)gets stored in an array and not into databse.
    I a fresher in objective c so if u could post back a code it would be sweet, as i searched almost evry site.
Thanks!

```
    -(IBAction)submitDetails:(id)sender
    {
               sqlite3_stmt    *stm;
            const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &connectDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {

                UIImage *contactImage = imageView.image;
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(contactImage, 100);
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
                [defaults synchronize];
                NSLog(@"Data saved");             
                NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO STUDENTS (name,salary, gid,photo) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",?)", name.text,salary.text,gid.text,imageData] ;

                const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(connectDB, insert_stmt, -1, &stm, NULL); 
                NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirec = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imgePath = [documentsDirec stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"note.sqlite"];

    if(sqlite3_open([imgePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

        const char *sql = "insert into images (images) values (?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            UIImage *edtedImae = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(edtedImae);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 1, [dataForImage bytes], [dataForImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                NSLog(@"1st ..... %i",sqlite3_step(stm));
                NSLog(@" 2nd.... %i",SQLITE_DONE);
                if (sqlite3_step(stm) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {                   
                    NSString* aName=name.text;
                    NSString* aSalary=salary.text;
                    NSString* aGid=gid.text;

                   UIImage* aPhoto=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:aName salary:aSalary gid:aGid photo:aPhoto];  
               [rootObject.list addObject:person];
               [person release];                
                    status.text = @"Contact added";
                    NSLog(@"contact added %@  %@",name.text,gid.text);
                    NSLog(@"the count in person list is %i",[rootObject.list count]);
                    name.text = @"";
                    gid.text = @"";
                    salary.text = @"";

                } 
                else
                {
                    status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(stm);
                sqlite3_close(connectDB);      
            }


    }
```

Comment: the image size is 50KB, i am trying to select an image form the photo gallery using UIPickerView. i am getting an error in this if loop.... if (sqlite3_step(stm) == SQLITE_DONE), so its not inserting, my sqlite_step(stm) value is coming as 21.  Thanks for reponding Oscar.

Comment: There is also an example project for using SQLite here you can refer to: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

It has classes for accessing SQLite in a more traditional database way that I feel makes things easier. It also has the guid method I mention in the answer below.

Comment: First you need to format your source better.  Then you need to check your return codes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't save the image in the database if you can avoid it. Instead, use columns to store the file name and any other attributes and then save the image as a document. I use a guid method to create file names. Don't forget to remove the document if you should remove the db entry.